# Why does my bar's sourround color doesn't match in tkinter in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, progress-bar

I can't make the surroudning of the bar match with the background. All of other things are matching with the background but this is not match it.

```
# Create a progress bar
progress_var = DoubleVar()
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(canvas,variable=progress_var, length=400, mode='determinate')
canvas.create_window(250, 650, anchor="center", window=progress_bar)
```

[image]

Comment: `tkinter` widget does not support transparent background.